# sql parameter error when convert into view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, view

im newbie in sql and im wondering why this one goes error when i create my sql query into a view

mysql query :

```
SELECT staffid AS staff,   
(SELECT count( feedback )FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = staff AND feedback =1) AS a,
(SELECT count( feedback )FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = staff AND feedback =2) AS b,
(SELECT count( feedback )FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = staff AND feedback =3) AS c,
(SELECT count( feedback )FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = staff AND feedback =4) AS d
FROM msqueue
GROUP BY staffid
```

this query result is like what i want

```
|staff| a | b | c | d |     
|d1111| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |    
|d1234| 1 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
```

but when i create query as a view
the result is

```
|staff| a | b | c | d |     
|d1111| 1 | 3 | 5 | 0 |    
|d1234| 1 | 3 | 5 | 0 |
```

Please help me what happen with this code.. thanks a lot

Comment: Finally got it, you cannot create sub queries in views in mysql. Workaround: create a view for each subquery... but before you start creating 5 views, have a look at my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT staffid AS staff,   
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue n WHERE n.staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =1) AS a,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue n WHERE n.staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =2) AS b,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue n WHERE n.staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =3) AS c,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue n WHERE n.staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =4) AS d
FROM msqueue m
GROUP BY staffid
```

In your original query you used the alias of column `staffid` of the main select to pair that with the `staffid` column of the subquery. This was not enough to distinguish between the two columns and as a result you got the sums over everything in every row. By using the table alias `m` and `n` in front of the column names we can now clearly address the two 
columns.

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab25a9/1

You can even leave out the tables alias in the subquery, like

```
SELECT staffid AS staff,   
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =1) AS a,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =2) AS b,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =3) AS c,
(SELECT count(*) FROM msqueue WHERE staffid = m.staffid AND feedback =4) AS d
FROM msqueue m
GROUP BY staffid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab25a9/2

**Edit**

After all this "clever-mouthing" from my side I just discovered, that your original statement works - at least "on its own" (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab25a9/4). I have not tried putting it in a view yet. Maybe that is the point when things start to go wrong. The safer option is definitely using table alias names.

---

Yes, ist *does* go wrong, when you put it in a view! But everything is OK with at least one table alias for the outer query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5f1e/1

I tested it first using **MySql**, but the statements are the same and it works just the same in **SQL-Server**, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5f1e/1

Comment: nice solution..now i get what makes it wrong..it need an alias for the main table.. thanks a lot... it works..

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got access to a mysql server to test this, but just in general SQL terms this might be a simpler solution:

```
SELECT 
   staffid AS staff,   
   SUM(CASE WHEN feedback = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
   SUM(CASE WHEN feedback = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
   SUM(CASE WHEN feedback = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c,
   SUM(CASE WHEN feedback = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d
FROM 
   msqueue
GROUP BY 
   staffid
```

Comment: Nice solution! And ... everybody has access to a MySql server ;-), see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a156/1.

Comment: my query works fine before i create my query into a view, but thanks to @cars10 , it only need an alias for the table not for the column..